# MongoDB Raw query to select documents which are in given datetime period

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, laravel-5.3, php-5.6

I want to select documents which are in user given date time period like between :

```
$from_date : "2017-01-07 09:08:59" To `$to_date : "2017-08-09 09:08:59"`
```

I'm using laravel framework and jenssegers/laravel-mongodb mongodb driver to run my query, And this is my Raw query :

```
 $normal_banners = BannerView::raw(function ($collection) use ($id, $from_date, $to_date) {
      $conditions = [
         ["camp_id" => ['$eq' => $id]],
         ['$or' => [
              ['seat_target_status' => ['$eq' => true]],
              ['seat_target_status' => ['$eq' => false]]
         ]],
         ['camp_target_status' => ['$eq' => false]],
         ];

         if ($from_date) {
            $conditions[] = ['created_at' => ['$gte' => $from_date]];
         }

         return $collection->aggregate([
            ['$match' => ['$and' => $conditions]],
         ]);
    })->count();
```

But my problem is that it returns 0 as result; while there are 16 documents in this time period.

I've tried this method to get the count of them but still 0 result :

```
   $normal_banners = BannerView::Where('camp_id', $id)
        ->where(function ($query) {$query->where('seat_target_status', true)->orWhere('seat_target_status', false);
           })
        ->where('camp_target_status', false)
        ->where("created_at", ">=", $from_date)
        ->count();
```

FYI : I've converted datetime of input to ISODate Which is the mongodb datatype for `created_at` field.

```
$Fromdatetime = $request->input('from_date');
$from_date = new DateTime($Fromdatetime);
$from_date = $from_date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

mongodb field data type is :

```
 "updated_at": ISODate("2017-04-10T09:35:58.641Z"),
   "created_at": ISODate("2017-04-10T09:35:58.641Z")
```

My input data type is : `"2017-01-07T09:08:59+0000"`

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this problem using Carbon::createDateFrom method, it create a UTC date time   base on my input :

Inputs :

```
{
  "from_date": "2017-03-10",
  "to_date": "2017-04-09"
}
```

Converting input dates :

```
$from_date_arr = explode("-",$request->input('from_date'));
$from_date = Carbon::createFromDate($from_date_arr[0],$from_date_arr[1],$from_date_arr[2]);

$to_date_arr = explode("-",$request->input('to_date'));
$to_date = Carbon::createFromDate($to_date_arr[0],$to_date_arr[1],$to_date_arr[2]);
```

And This is the query I run which worked :

```
$normal_banners = BannerView::Where('camp_id', $id)
    ->where(function ($query) {$query->where('seat_target_status', true)->orWhere('seat_target_status', false);
         })
    ->where('camp_target_status', false)
    ->where("created_at", ">=",$from_date)
    ->where("created_at", "<=",$to_date)
    ->count();
```

There is a strange problem still with jessenger driver which whereBetween is not working and we should use two where clause to make it work.

Hope solves others problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have to "put in braces" orWhere function and in your raw query you are testing $to_date with updated_at column, but in Eloquent code you are making between with created_at column

```
$targeted_banners = BannerView::Where('camp_id', $id)
  ->where(function($query){$query->where('seat_target_status', true)->orWhere('seat_target_status', false);})
  ->where('camp_target_status', false)
  ->where("created_at", ">=" $from_date)
  ->where("updated_at", "<=", $to_date)
  ->count();
```

Comment: There is no difference between created_at and update_at  But you are right I should check a single field for date time check , Let me try your approach.

Comment: @Autisa_z I've tried your approach - the or statement part is working and thanks for it, but the date check still not working and I get 0 result.

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini and what is format of the columns created_at/uploated_at?

Comment: They are ISODate :  "updated_at": ISODate("2017-04-10T09:35:58.641Z"),
   "created_at": ISODate("2017-04-10T09:35:58.641Z")

Comment: Well, then I think, that this is the problem, you are trying to compare DateTime format with ISODate format.

Comment: @Austisa_z any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: I've fixed the datetime formate :  $Fromdatetime = $request->input('from_date');
                $from_date = new DateTime($Fromdatetime);
                $from_date = $from_date->format(DateTime::ATOM);   When I echo $from_date I get : "2017-01-07T09:08:59+00:00",  But still I get 0 result .

Comment: I never worked with ISO dates, but ist problem the ending of date? in database you have "T09:35:58.641Z" but the variable is "T09:08:59+00:00".

Comment: I've checked that too , I've manually set "from_date": "2017-04-10T09:35:58.641Z" And run the code again but still no luck.